# Split string for make a Select case

Tags: vb.net, split, case, ini

i have a ini file where i read my data

**Ini File**

> myString=xxx;xxxxx;Alpha|Gamma

In my code i have a `Select Case`
In this case i want to put myString i do that

```
Dim _sString As String = myIniFile.myString.Data
```

In Data i have

> Alpha|Gamma

i `Split` my `sString`

```
Dim _sWords As String() = _sString.Split(New char() {"|"c})
```

and i can do my `Select Case`

```
Select Case myValue
   Case _sWords(0), _sWords(1)
...
```

My question is how can i do if in my Ini file i have x value

> myString=xxx;xxxxx;Alpha|Gamma|.......

How can i do for my `Select Case` consider my news values .?

Comment: What do you want to do with the x values exactly? Ignore them?

Comment: I have a difficult time understanding your question. Are your new values beyond Alpha|Gamma? Do you wanna ignore the first 2 xxx.. values and only consider what is after that as your "Data"?

Comment: Is your INI file in the correct format as standard practise says that everything after the semi colon is a comment unless escaped: [INI File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to comprehend, but I'll take a shot:

```
Dim data As String = "xxx;xxxxx;Alpha|Gamma"

For Each item As String In data.Split(";").Last.Split("|")
  Select Case item
    Case "Alpha"
      MessageBox.Show("I am Alpha")
    Case "Gamma"
      MessageBox.Show("I am Gamma")
  End Select
Next
```

In your post, I'm not sure where "myValue" is coming from or what it is.  That might help.

Comment: ok for your response but if i have news values im my data variable how can manage my Select Case

Comment: @Mercer If you create a new value "Beta", you will have to add a Case "Beta" to your Select Case list.